# How to get rid of Black Screen when hiding view iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, view

My problem is once i have sent the email or have cancelled out of the Mailcomposer i am segueing within the completion block after dismissing.This shows the previous screen for a split second before performing the segue. I have been trying to stop the previous screen from showing before the segue has been performed without putting a delay on the main thread, i have tried setting the `[self.view setHidden:YES];` which works but instead of it showing the previous screen it just shows a black screen for a split second which looks worse in my opinion. My second attempt was setting the background colour of the view to white but this seems to have no effect. I have also tried using the alpha and opaque properties as well but both don't seem to have any effect on the view.

Can anyone suggest anything to get round this problem? code is below.

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller
      didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                    error:(NSError*)error
{
    if(error) NSLog(@"ERROR - mailComposeController: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    [self.view setHidden:YES];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toCompletedOrderList" sender:nil];
    }];

    return;
}
```

Comment: you are hiding your view and then setting background color, try to take out the performSegue out of the completion block.

Comment: I've tried that as well and i still get the same outcome. Thanks anyway.